# Property does not exist on type after binding with formControlName

Tags: angular, typescript

I was watching this tutorial:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aHD7PLXKTsQ

Somehow, in the tutorial, there is no need to type `nestedGroup.controls.field.invalid` when checking for validation, instead, simply `field.invalid`. However, in my case I get error: Property 'region' does not exist on type 'AddCountryFormComponent'.

.html:

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <form [formGroup]="nestedForm">
      <!-- single field info -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
              <label for="nameText" class="">Country Name</label>
              <input type="text" formControlName="name" [ngClass]="{'form-control': true,
              'is-invalid': name.invalid && name.touched,
              'is-valid': name.valid}" id="nameText" placeholder="Enter name">
              <small id="fnHelp" *ngIf="name.errors?.required && name.touched" class="form-text custom-invalid-feedback">Field is required</small>
              <small id="fnHelp" *ngIf="name.errors?.minlength && name.touched" class="form-text custom-invalid-feedback">Value must contain atleast 2 characters</small>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
              <label for="populationText" class="">Country Population</label>
              <input type="text" formControlName="population" [ngClass]="{'form-control': true,
              'is-invalid': population.invalid && population.touched,
              'is-valid': population.valid}" id="populationText" placeholder="Enter population">
              <small id="fnHelp" *ngIf="population.errors?.required && population.touched" class="form-text custom-invalid-feedback">Field is required</small>
              <small id="fnHelp" *ngIf="population.errors?.minlength && population.touched" class="form-text custom-invalid-feedback">Value must contain atleast 2 characters</small>
   
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
              <label for="regionText" class="">Region</label>
              <input type="text" formControlName="region" [ngClass]="{'form-control': true,
              'is-invalid': region.invalid && region.touched,
              'is-valid': region.valid}" id="regionText" placeholder="Enter region">
              <small id="fnHelp" *ngIf="region.errors?.required && region.touched" class="form-text custom-invalid-feedback">Field is required</small>
              <small id="fnHelp" *ngIf="region.errors?.minlength && region.touched" class="form-text custom-invalid-feedback">Value must contain atleast 2 characters</small>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: I suspect there is a property in the ts the points to the specific control in the form.

Comment: There isn't. All properties with such names are only in form controls.

Comment: I added link to the source

Comment: Ok, you have a different form (the contents). In that video he uses a ngFor and then uses that variable to get the controls (and their valid state).

Comment: That's true only for the addresses. Take a look at `firstName` and `lastName`

Comment: He has getters for that. He only created it in the video for one as an example (min 16:38) and leaves the rest out of the video because it would take too much time. I didn't look at it, but he provides a link for the final code btw.

Comment: I didnt see the getters, thank you!